# Classes, generated with Maven and Dagger, are not visible to ADT in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, dagger

I've set up a project with Dagger added to classpath, with all those M2E connectors, etc. In my pom.xml I have

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.squareup.dagger</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.jakewharton</groupId>
                    <artifactId>butterknife</artifactId>
                    <version>5.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Everything is also added to Eclipse project settings, so when I change something in my Dagger module, it is reflected automatically in the generated Java files under

```
target/generated-sources/annotations
```

This folder is also attached as a source folder to the project.

So far so good, when I run application via ADT on the emulator I see an exception saying

```
06-21 09:51:17.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application XXX:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module adapter for class XXX could not be loaded.
Please ensure that code generation was run for this module.
```

As far as I understand it means that folder "target/generated-sources/annotations" is not visible for ADT when it tries to compile the project.

Currently I have 2 ideas:

- Add this folder to the classpath of ADT
- Generate files to standard Android folders so ADT can see them

Unfortunately, I have not found how to do either of those. Dagger documentation is also a bit too brief and obscure on this topic.

So how does it usually work in Eclipse, when you use Maven and Dagger?

**UPDATE:** I've done all the steps from the "possible duplicate" question above, but my problem is not solved. I will state this again: the files **are created** during build, they are just not visible to emulator for some reason.

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate, because in that other question the person who asked was missing JavaWriter lib. I definitely have it in classpath, because the files are generated successfully. If I would not have it, then the files would not generate at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone stucks with the same problem, here is how I solved it. I added next lines to pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <outputDirectory>bin/classes</outputDirectory>
...
```

This means that all the usual stuff continues to go to "target" folder as usual during build, but all the classes from all the source folders go to "bin/classes". This **must** be set for ADT to work correctly. I don't know, if ADT can work with any other folder for classes, but by default it cannot. Now you can right click project and choose "Maven/Update Project..." to set all the output folders to "bin/classes". This fixes the problem, ADT runs application properly on the emulator with all the required classes.